# Using event modifier .prevent in Vue to submit form without redirection

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vue in my application and I would like to know how to submit a form but avoid redirection.
According to the official Vue doc it can be achieved in the following way:

```
<!-- the submit event will no longer reload the page -->
<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"></form>
```

Here is my part of my form:

```
<form class="myForm" action="/page" method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="e-mail" v-model="email">
    <button @click="myFunction()">
```

It sorta works in the sense that the page is no longer redirected but I get an error saying that `onSubmit` method is not defined. So What I don't understand is how I should define it. On the other hand I could just write `@submit@prevent` but as far as I understand it completely prevents submission and that's not what I'm looking for. 
Is there a proper way to do this without ajax, axios and that sort of technologies?
What I want is myFunction to execute and form to submit but I would want to avoid redirection.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`onSubmit` should be a function within your `methods` property on the vue instance. I.e

```
methods: {
  onSubmit () {
    // DO Something
  }
}
```

Then as the docs say, using `<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"></form>` is correct. I use this in my app.

See the example below. The message will change once the button is clicked without a page refresh.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      test: 'BEFORE SUBMIT'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit () {
      this.test = 'AFTER SUBMIT'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{test}}
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <button>Submit!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: For a form with only a single input element (like a search box), use `@submit.native.prevent`.

Answer (score 22):

Just use `@submit.prevent` (without any equal signs).

Then, define `@click="doAction()"` on the button.

Comment: This is the simplest solution, and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems to throw `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

Try `@submit.prevent="myFunction()"`, and your `button` could instead be `<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>`. The `submit` type will trigger the form to submit, and the `submit.prevent` will prevent the default submit behavior and execute `myFunction` as desired.

This has the additional benefit of triggering form validation for required input fields!

Comment: For what it's worth, a `button`'s default `type` is `submit`. (This is counter-intuitive to me.)

Comment: okay, but how do I check if it actually makes a post request?

Comment: @Bill Check the network tab of your browser console. Have it open just before you click submit and you should see new network activity. If you're not seeing any new activity, be sure to check for errors. If you continue to have trouble, be sure to include the `myFunction` code so that we may examine it for problems.

Comment: The strange thing is that I do have the network tab open but I don't see any new network activity when I press enter and submit the form. 
Would you please tell me what `@submit.prevent` does? What's it for?
In the official documentations it says: "the submit event will no longer reload the page". I want to understand why.

Comment: @Bill `submit.prevent` is shorthand for "on submit, do event.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting". The entire `submit.prevent="myFunction()"` means "stop the form from submitting the normal way and execute `myFunction()` instead". If you want to submit the form the ordinary way, i.e. with a page refresh, this is NOT the way to do it. Otherwise, in `myFunction()` you need to be performing an ajax request and then redirecting once it's finished.

Comment: Thank you, now it's more clear to me. Actually instead of doing a redirection I want to show a user a piece of info after they click submit. So, as far as I understand the only way to do it is to rewrite browser's default behavior by using `@submit.prevent="myFunction()"` to prevent submitting on click and making a post request inside myFunction, correct?

Comment: if everything is as you say, then this `action="/subscribe" method="post"` doesn't make sense if I use `@submit.prevent="myFunction()"`, does it?

Comment: @Bill That's right. With Vue.js, it makes more sense to simply update the data after an ajax POST request than it does to submit the form the ordinary way. You'll accomplish the same thing while avoiding reloading the entire page.

Comment: this is working,but it will execute two http requests (*options* and *POST*) what is the reason for that

Comment: @Kalanka There should not be a case of two HTTP requests occurring. You may be doing something strange with your code. Unfortunately I can't tell what that is without seeing it. If you would like to figure out what's wrong, please submit your own question with the relevant code, or create a chat room and invite me to it if you wish to discuss the problem further without opening a new question. Either way, we should avoid continuing to discuss your problem here and should move this discussion elsewhere.

Comment: I know this is old, but for future readers, the reason for the two http requests is that the AJAX POST call is most likely the result of CORS.

Answer (score 2):

`<form @submit.prevent="saveData()" method="post">`
`<!-- Add all the input filed -->`
`<button type="submit"> Save </button>`
`</form>`

This will avoid redirection of the form also we can validate input fields.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the only the solution that actually ran native browser form input validation, worked with pressing a keyboard return/enter button, worked while clicking the submit button, and did not result in the browser reloading/redirecting. I think this is the best answer.